# Silverlight Images won't show in web

Tags: silverlight, silverlight-5.0

This is a nubie question, I have a silverlight 5 (VB) application that runs fine and displays all 3 png images when I run it from my PC. When the app is put onto the web it doesn't show the png Images. The build I have selected for the png files is Resource? I checked the XAP.zip to see if the png files are there and they are.
I've done a bit of research and found that I may need some coding to enable me to get these up and running on the web unfortunately everything I've looked at is in C. I have found these two pieces of code :

```
<Imagex:Name="myIamge"Source="../computer.JPG"></Image>

myIamge.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri("../Image/computer.JPG", UriKind.Relative));
```

Are these two pieces of code what I need?

Do I need them both together?

Does anyone know the conversion Of the second piece of code from c to vb

Is there anyone out there that can tell me how to do this in silverlight VB

Regards
Will

Comment: Please post some code. Could for example have to do with sandbox restrictions, depending on where you load the images from.

Comment: Sorry this is where my inexperience is showing. The scenario is that I have written the app, run and tested it from the desktop and I am now sending the xap file and the test sheet to someone else who is trying to get it onto a website. The png files are being loaded from my computer into visual studio and then I'm just doing a build to the release folder in the bin for the xap. Unfortunately I don't have code for this , can you help?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Are these two pieces of code what I need?

Probably, hard to say because you did not explain us where you put physically your 'computer.JPG'

- Do I need them both together?

No, if you display this image only once, and never change it after, you do no need the code behind. Just use your xaml declaration.

So, what you have done seems pretty correct: your image should be declared as ressource, and you use the path to specify where the image is, compare to the XAML file using your image.

Thus, for instance if the declaration is in the MainPage.xaml (to the root of your project), and your image in an Image folder, this declaration is correct.

```
<Image x:Name="myImage" Source="Image/computer.jpg"/>
```

If despite this, you cannot see your image, I will recommand you to check the website where you deploy your xap file, maybe there is an error explaining why the image can not show up (MIME type, .net version?...)

Comment: Yes I had the image file path set locally and the build set to content